# Cherenkov radiation in glass via electron tube?

Tags: x-rays, cherenkov-radiation

Recently I was experimenting with an vacuum tube attached to a wimshurst machine and measuring the X-Rays emissions. While doing so, I noticed the the surface of the tube began to glow blue in some areas. It appeared to be from the inside. Now, this variant of tube was known to produce X-Rays at 25kv, but since I did not want to put more Risk in one experiment, I elected to use my hand cranked wimshurst machine instead. This would lower the current, but increase the voltage to roughly 80–100kv. I was still producing the limited X-Rays I was expecting, so I doubt it was due to the X-Rays, so I wonder if I was simply pushing the electrons fast enough that when they hit the glass they were moving faster than light in a glass medium? I was able to get a rather poor quality image from my cell phone in the dark room, which I have attached. [image: image showing blue light emissions from surface of tube]

Comment: Is it focused forward like Cherenkov, or is it isotropic like scintillation? Plastics scintillate, glasses, not so much, but there could be something in the glass.

Answer (score 1):

An electron with energy 100kV has a speed of about 0.52c, if I am not mistaken, which is slower than the speed of light in glass (typical refractive index of glass is 1.5), so, unless the voltage is significantly higher, you probably don't have Cherenkov radiation. The light can be from some discharge, whether it is in vacuum, in glass, or in air, I am not sure.

EDIT (May 22,2023): Sorry, I was indeed mistaken. Actually, an electron with energy 100kV has a speed of about 0.55c, but this does not change my conclusions.

Comment: Indeed. Actually $100~\text{keV}$ has even lower speed,- about $0.44c$, so even in impure [flint glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refractive_indices) which has upper bound of refractive index of $1.9$,- electron speed has deficit of $0.08c$ for reaching threshold of Cherenkov radiation.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas : I got a different result - 0.55C for 100kV (please see my edit).

Comment: Yes, I have messed-up with relativistic kinetic energy, when I've re-calculated for relativistic energies, I've got also $0.549c$ electron speed. But then it depends on quality of glass. If it's impure flint glass with refractive index of $n=1.9$, then such electron surpasses medium's light speed by about $0.02c$. So about the Cherenkov radiation.